# an weird message by lauching program

Tags: assembly, x86

I have very need help because i have create this assembly program 
( eject /dev/sr0) and when i run the program. 
The cd open but I have a weird message : "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"
Why did I receive this error message?
Thank's you very much and happy day =)

```
[section .text]

global _start
_start:
    mov al, 5
    cdq
    push edx
    push dword 0x3072732f
    push dword 0x7665642f
    mov ebx, esp
    mov cx, 0xfff
    sub cx, 0x3e7
    sub cx, 0x418
    int 0x80
    mov ebx, eax
    mov al, 54
    mov cx, 0x5309
    cdq
    int 0x80
```

Comment: Your assembly is… weird. Is there a specific reason you're doing it this way?

Comment: Write the code in the simplest way possible until you have something that works. _Then_ you can start thinking about obfuscating the code (assuming that you actually need it for some reason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the first system call is an `open` and the second is the `ioctl` that ejects the tray. What do you think happens afterwards? You forgot to end your program, so the cpu will continue executing whatever is there in memory, until it hits a fault. You might want to add something equivalent to `mov eax, 1; int 0x80`.

Finally, the usual advice: learn to use a debugger.